# Facebook Posting on Friend's Wall fails after i publish my website on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I am  implementing Facebook Wall post on friends,Everything is working fine when i run my aaplication on localhost,it will post successfully but when i publish my webapplication on IIS , it'll not post any thing on facebook wall, I am using IIS 6.1(windows 7) and i am using dotnet framework 4.0, I have separate Appid and Appkey for my localhost and for publishing site,
below is the code i am implementing

```
   FacebookClient app = new FacebookClient(fbtoken);

                    var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    args["message"] = "message";
                    args["caption"] = "This is caption!";
                    args["description"] = "This is description!";
                    args["name"] = "This is name!";   

app.Post("/" + friendId + "/feed", args);
```

where friendID is retrieving from Facebook Friend's list, i am using Facebook C# SDK of codeplex, and fbtoken i am getting after FB login(Login is without popup)
What other settings/ configuration do i need to be able to post on friend's wall after publishing my application on IIS???
Even Sandbox option is disabled in my fb app

Answer (score 0):

If your project is configured to use the Facebook JavaScript SDK, you have to use the FacebookWebClient class to make the requests, which sets up the access token automatically.

This distinction is explained in the documentation (which is being ported to the project's new site), in the examples about how to start you project:
[http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website%20%28With%20Javascript%20SDK%29]

```
public ActionResult Profile()
{
    var client = new FacebookWebClient();

    dynamic me = client.Get("me");
    ViewBag.Name = me.name;
    ViewBag.Id = me.id;

    return View();
}
```

> **Note** 
>   It is important to note that we are using FacebookWebClient in the above code and not FacebookClient. FacebookWebClient inherits from FacebookClient. The only difference between the two is that FacebookWebClient automatically retrieves the current users access token from the session. If you use FacebookClient, you must provide the access token manually before you make an API call."